# Magento Quantity increment by dropdown

Tags: magento, product, dropdown

Hi I would like to have two"Add to cart" buttons which add specified quantities for my products and remove the input field i want quntity drop down instead of this.

=

I'd like

[Add a single to cart]

[Add 25 to cart]

Wondering on the best way to do this, I would also like to implement this on the product listing.

Thanks